# how do I detect key presses with just one method in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, keypress

I'm trying to paint  6 colors, 10 shapes, a jpeg image, and 3 things that change when a key is pressed in java.

**However I'm trying to program all of this in one method.** I've done everything else except detecting a key press. I've looked at a lot of examples, but all of them use different methods or classes that work together to detect a key press. **But how to do I detect key presses and at the same time change pictures/images in JPanel all in just one method.**

I tried to write some code but it doesn't work (nothing shows up on the JPanel/screen) Here's my code so far:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

      BufferedImage photo = null;
      try 
      {
       File file = new File("holiday.jfif");
       photo = ImageIO.read(file);
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
       g.drawString("Problem reading the file", 100, 100);
      }
      g.drawImage(photo,0,0,800,800,null);

      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillRect(120,300,100,100 );
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillOval(270,130,50,100 );
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE );
      g.fillRect(350,200,100,150 );
      g.setColor(Color.PINK);
      g.fillOval(460, 270, 50, 50);

      g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      g.fillArc(500, 300, 110, 100, 5, 150);
      g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g.fillRect(500,450,100,100);
      g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g.fillOval(550,500,100,100);
      int[] xpoints = {50,150,20,180};
      int[] ypoints = {500,500,550,550};
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawPolygon(xpoints,ypoints,4);
      int[] xpoint = {250,220,380,350};
      int[] ypoint = {500,550,550,500};
      g.drawPolygon(xpoint,ypoint,4);
      int[] x = {600,500,700};
      int[] y = {20,100,100};
      g.drawPolygon(x,y,3);
      g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
      g.fillRect(10,50,220,30);
      g.fillRect(115,80,20,100);

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String press;
      boolean stop = false;  
      while(!stop)
      {
       //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       press = input.next();

       if (press != null)
       {
        g.clearRect(115,80,20,100);
        g.clearRect(500,450,100,100);
        stop = true;
       }
     }


   }
```

Comment: "*But how to do I detect key presses and at the same time change pictures/images in JPanel all in just one method"* You don't, because that's not how it works.  Instead, you use the key bindings API to bind an `Action` to a `KeyStroke` and when it's triggered, you update some internal state which allows you to change the way in which your output is rendered

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the API works. You need to start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to get a better understanding of how the paint process works. You should also look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to gain  a better understanding of how a event driven environment works (and why your code isn't working)

Comment: And finally [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) so you can learn how to monitor for user input